# Reset Smart values to factory defaults for a Samsung NVMe SSD?

Tags: ssd, smart, reset, factory-defaults, samsung-ssd

Here https://askubuntu.com/a/687455/974560 is a quesion regarding resetting smart values to factory defaults on old spinning S-ATA disks. In the comments is a link to a youtube video which is not available anymore on youtube. In internet archive you can still see the video https://web.archive.org/web/20170519202031if_/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PPmbxNAWyg
Also in the post is described that you can reset smart attributes with a RS232 cable and the commands described there.

So is there a similiar way to reset smart counters to factory defaults on Samsung NVMe SSDs?

EDIT: Can you please explain why you vote down? This is a very legitimate question, since as already mentioned in the comments if this would be possible you could only buy used hardware from trusted source.
I didn't expect to get voted down for this questions, meaning I'm afraid asking further questions and that is not the principle of stackexchange.

Comment: God I hope not. I'd never buy a second hand device from anyone, ever, and would not touch "refurbished" parts with a barge pole either. The comments on that answer also mention that it was a "feature" that got locked down. I can see absolutely no legitimate reason for a home user to be able to reset those values.

Comment: Manufacturers should keep that process as a secret. As opposed to a car where you can find evidence of age this does not seem to be the case when it comes to a wear-prone article like flash storage.

Comment: @Hannes How you ask a question matters. Your question reads like "I want to do this. Show me how." Rather than "Is this really possible and if so wouldn't that be a massive risk or problem?" and explaining that would completely change the tone and reception of your question. I know that distinction is why I downvoted. Also the fact that reading the comments on your linked answer would have given you at least half an answer.

Comment: @Mokubai: Sorry I wanted to sound it as neutral. So neither that I wan't to do it nor the consequences that you than can't buy used drives anymore. I gave reference that showed how easy this change was. I did not write the whole procedure. I mean even if it is possible like for refurbished harddrives, perhaps they need a special key which is not available for the public, then you would be safe.

Comment: The problem is that none of that shows in your question here. Even on the post you linked all the other answers go into great detail on *why this should not be possible* so just browsing around away from one single answer would have told you far more. Admittedly that one answer is upvoted, but it is not the only answer, nor is it the accepted one. Just picking one piece of borderline wrong information on the internet and ignoring all the other information *right there with it* makes people assume that you are trying to replicate *that one thing*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no justification for this goal other than fraudulous action - the same thing when reseting the odometer.